# Fourier transform as change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-transform, change-of-basis

The Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ of some function $f$ is often presented as a change of basis to a basis of complex exponentials. This however begs the question: since $\hat{f}$ is expressed with respect to a basis, is $f$ too expressed with respect to some basis?

In a linear algebra setting, the initial and final bases are clearly defined, for example from the standard basis to some linear combination of it. Here, however, it seems that the initial basis is just left out of the discussion.

Comment: Fourier transform is not a change of basis, if it was the function would remain the same. But, clearly, it changes. You can express both $f$ and $\hat{f}$ in the basis of complex exponentials.

Comment: In functional analysis you have countless choices of basis functions and that's especially true for well-behaved functions. Like for smooth functions I can just take a polynomial basis and represent them by their power series. For Fourier transforms trigonometric functions provide a natural basis to examine periodic functions which is what motivates the use of complex numbers since it combines sine and cosine into a single expression using the exponential function.

Comment: @CyclotomicField it's a detail, but aren't there smooth functions which cannot be written as power series?

Comment: @charmd I typically use smooth to mean infinitely continuously differentiable but I don't think that's universal.

Comment: But there are smooth functions (in the sense you meant; $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$) which are nowhere analytic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function. Could these still be written in a basis of polynomials? This is the point I wanted to clarify

Answer (score 3):

You can write $f(x)=c_1\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(p)\delta(x-p)dp$ and $f(x)=c_2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(p)e^{ipx} dp$ [with constants chosen according to your convention for delta functions and Fourier transforms]. I think a physicist would say that you have expressed $f$ in a 'position basis' or a 'momentum basis' in the two cases, so the Fourier transform can be thought of as a change of basis as long as you imagine $f$ as originally expressed in the delta function 'position basis'.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what mcd has written, the usual way to expand in the orthonormal basis $e_n$ is:
$$
              f = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\langle f,e_n\rangle e_n.
$$
That's essentially what you're doing with the Fourier transform with regard to a basis with a continuous index 's' that ranges over the real numbers:
$$
            f = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left\langle f,\frac{e^{isx'}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right\rangle \frac{e^{isx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}ds
$$